# Do the min-x and min-y of the viewbox map to the coordinates used in the svg viewport?

Tags: svg, browser

If we have an `svg` element created like this.

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="50 50 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Does the `viewBox` start at x(50px), y(50px)?  So essentially in the center of the svg viewport and extend out to the bottom right corner of the `viewport`?

Comment: The effect of  the `viewBox` attribute is way easier to explain with a svg example containing rendered elements. I highly recommend to always include a complete svg sample with a visual result – ideally as a snippet. When it comes to svg, we still have a lot of rendering inconsistencies between different browser engines, so a reproducible code snippet can both help to find workarounds or issues that should be filed as bug reports.